# Filter Products by Distribution Center Quantity Channel advisor REST API

Tags: django, channeladvisor

I am working on a **django** project in which I am fetching products from **Channel Advisor** platform using the file export feature. I am using the filter '**$filter=ProfileID eq  and TotalQuantity gt 0'**.

https://developer.channeladvisor.com/working-with-products/product-exports

I would like to query the product based on the **value present in 'Qty Avail Warehouse' field**  present in catalogs listing page instead of 'TotalQuantity'. Or **filter by distribution center quantity** eg: those products having stock greater than 0 in 'Phoenix' distribution center.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion is to override the `get_queryset` method of your `ModelViewSet`:

**views.py**

```py
def BaseAPIView(...):

    ''' base view for other views to inherit '''

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = self.queryset

        # get filter request from client:
        filter_string = self.request.query_params.get('filter')

        # apply filters if they are passed in:
        if filters: 
            filter_dictionary = json.loads(filter_string)
            queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_dictionary)

        return queryset
```

The request url will now look like, for example: `my_website.com/api/products?filter={"name":"book"}`

Or more precisely: `my_website.com/api/products?filter=%7B%22name%22:%22book%22%7D`

Which can be built like:

**script.js**

```js
// using ajax as an example:
var filter = JSON.stringify({
  "name" : "book"
});

$.ajax({
   "url" : "my_website.com/api/products?filter=" + filter,
   "type" : "GET",
   ...
});
```

**Some advantages:**

- no need to specify which fields can be filtered on each view class
- write it once, use it everywhere
- front end filtering looks exactly like django filtering
- can do the same with `exclude`

**Some disadvantages:**

- potential security risks if you want some fields to be non-filterable
- less intuitive front-end code to query a table

Overall, this approach has been far more useful for me than any packages out there.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What we are doing is triggering CA rest api to fetch products using the above said filters. I would like to know if there is any option to call CA rest api so that I can fetch products by filtering the required distribution center. Sorry for confusing you. Their document is given in the url: https://developer.channeladvisor.com/working-with-products/retrieve-products/retrieve-all-products-created-on-or-after-date